# Why php 8.1 has a different behavior with /tmp/ directory read/write?

Tags: php, linux, image

I'm using [ImageManipulator](https://gist.github.com/marplemr/9178810) library to resize/crop/save images on the server.

It was working well on the old server (Ubuntu 18.04 and PHP 7.2). But now, on the new server (Ubuntu 22.04 and PHP 8.1) [this line](https://gist.github.com/marplemr/9178810#file-imagemanipulator-php-L104) throws:

```
> No image set
```

Noted that I put a `var_dump` inside `__construct` to see if the image exist and here is the result:

```
function __construct($file = null){
    var_dump($file); die;
    ...

//=> string(14) "/tmp/phppIOCdU"
```

So, apparently the image exists as a temp file, so, why `!is_resource($this->image)` is `true`? Any idea how can I fix it?

---

Also, here is how I use that library:

```
function fitImageSizeAndSave($img, $target_file){
    try {

        $width_and_height = 200;
        $size = getimagesize($img);
        $ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height
        if( $ratio < 1) {
            $width  = $width_and_height;
            $height = $width_and_height/$ratio;
        }
        else {
            $width = $width_and_height*$ratio;
            $height = $width_and_height;
        }

        require_once INACCESSIBLE . 'image_manipulator.php';
        $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($img);

        $manipulator->resample($width, $height);

        $width  = $manipulator->getWidth();
        $height = $manipulator->getHeight();
        $centreX = round($width / 2);
        $centreY = round($height / 2);

        // our dimensions will be 200x130
        $x1 = $centreX - ($width_and_height / 2);
        $y1 = $centreY - ($width_and_height / 2);

        $x2 = $centreX + ($width_and_height / 2);
        $y2 = $centreY + ($width_and_height / 2);

        $manipulator->crop($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);

        $manipulator->save($target_file);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: _"why is true"_ Because it's a string, not a resource. It says so right in your dump. What else would it return?

Comment: @AlexHowansky well, I'm passing `$_FILES["imageToUpload"]["tmp_name"]` to it, it was working well on the old server. Should I change it?

Comment: Read the code of the constructor you posted. `@param string $file OPTIONAL Path to image file or image data as string` Follow the execution path. I'd guess that imagecreatefromstring() in setImageString() is failing, probably because you don't have the GD extension installed, and you're probably missing the error it's throwing.

Comment: @AlexHowansky You were right, the GD extension wasn't installed, I installed it and restarted both php8.1 and nginx ... but sadly still the same error exists :(

Comment: Have you called phpinfo to verify the extension is actually enabled now ...?

Comment: Oops sorry, I said setImageString(), I meant setImageFile(). Verify that setImageFile() is  being called. Add var_dump() at various points inside that method to see where it's failing. Enable error reporting so that you can see the exceptions.

Comment: I found a clue, the result of [this line](https://gist.github.com/marplemr/9178810#file-imagemanipulator-php-L53), for variable `$type` is `2`. Not something like `IMAGETYPE_JPEG`. @AlexHowansky

Comment: Yes @CBroe it's enabled

Comment: `IMAGETYPE_JPEG` is just an integer constant, so $type = 2 is not unexpected. Now add a `var_dump($this->image)` after line 60, to see if the call to `imagecreatefromjpeg()` worked.

Comment: Note, see the docs for `imagecreatefromjpeg()` -- that function might return false, which this library _does not account for_. E.g., if you give it a file that isn't a valid JPG, this will break silently.

Comment: @AlexHowansky The result of `var_dump($this->image)` after line 60 is `object(GdImage)#4 (0) {}`

Comment: That also looks okay. Anything else happening in _your_ code, between the constructor call that you pass the file path to, and the call of the `resample` method which throws the error?

Comment: I wonder if PHP 8- considered a GD object a resource, and PHP 8+ now doesn't...

Comment: @CBroe I edited my question and added how I use `resample`

Comment: Yep that's it -- PHP 7.4 returns true for `is_resource($gd)` while PHP 8+ returns false.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I see .. so any idea how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Conclusion -- this library is not compatible with PHP 8+. You _might_ be able to replace `is_resource` with `is_object` or `instanceof \GdImage` and just have it work. Maybe.

Comment: Ok @AlexHowansky I replaced all `is_resource` with `is_object` and now it's working. thanks for the time you spent for me